# Easy testing of HTML with emacs

Tags: emacs, nxhtml

Suppose I type some HTML code into emacs and would like to preview its result in a web browser without having type something outside of emacs. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command is `browse-url-of-buffer` not sure how it's bound in nxhtml.  In html-mode, it's <kbd>C-c C-v</kbd>.

Comment: It's not bound in nxhtml. But (global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-v") 'browse-url-of-buffer) in .emacs sets it in nxhtml-mode.